# What is the difference between var foo = new Love(); AND object foo = new Love();?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, c#-3.0, implicit-typing

As I am not familiar with implicit typing; can you please tell me the main differences between:

```
 var foo = new Love();
```

AND

```
object foo = new Love();
```

Answer (score 16):

In the first case the type of `foo` is `Love`. In the second case it is `object`.

Comment: Also don't forget boxing of value types when using object :)

Comment: Also, remember that true love cannot be abstracted as an object.

Answer (score 11):

```
var foo = new Love();
```

Here, the *static* type of variable `foo` is `Love`. It's equivalent to writing `Love foo = new Love();`.

```
object foo = new Love();
```

Here, the *static* type of variable `foo` is `object`. You cannot access any of Love's methods without using a cast first.

The *dynamic* type (or *runtime* type) of `foo` is `Love` in both cases, which is why `GetType` will return `Love` for both.

Answer (score 6):

With `var`, the compile *infers* the type of the variable based on the expression on the right-hand side of the assignment operator.

In other words,

```
var foo = new Love();
```

is *exactly* equivalent to

```
Love foo = new Love();
```

So all the members of `Love` will be available via `foo` - whereas if `foo` were declared to be of type `object`, you'd only have access to `GetHashCode()`, `ToString()`, `GetType()` and `Equals()`.

With `var`, you're still using static typing (as opposed to using `dynamic` in C# 4). You're just not explicitly stating the type of the variable - you're letting the compiler work it out for you. However, it does need to be a type that the compiler *can* work out. So for example, these are all invalid:

```
// All invalid
var a = null;
var b = delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Hello"); };
var c = x => Console.WriteLine("lambda: " + x);
var d = MethodName; // Attempted method group conversion
```

In these cases the compiler doesn't have enough information to work out which type you mean.

Comment: Also don't forget boxing of value types when using object :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = new Love();
```

here it equals to

```
Love foo = new Love();
```

sometimes we can use `var` to avoid long class name e.g. `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,string>>.` You can use all methods/properties of class Love.

```
object foo = new Love();
```

Now foo is considered to be an object, you can't see any method/property of class Love, but you can convert it back.